# Can visual studio guess the namespace by filename?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-2015

When I create a new class in Visual Studio (2015 Update 2, Community) via Add --> new item --> class in the project's context menu, it will automatically give the class the name of the file.

But can I do this with namespaces as well? So, let's assume that I have a default namespace `MyName.ProgramCategory.ProgramName`. What I want to do is to set the namespace in which the new class is in via the filename:

Filename: `SubNamespace.MyClass.cs` or `MyName.ProgramCategory.ProgramName.SubNamespace.MyClass.cs` or something like this, and the namespace automatically becomes `MyName.ProgramCategory.ProgramName.SubNamespace`.

I couldn't find any documentation of this online, so I'm not sure this is possible at all, but it would be good if I could do this, because I often leave classes in the wrong namespace after creating them, and it would save me a lot of frustration. So if this is possible, my question is: What is the format with which you can achieve automatic namespace naming?

Comment: Create a directory called `SubNamespace` then create the `MyClass.cs` inside that directory since by default folders inside a project are namespace providers.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice I could add directories. This is actually much cleaner than if they did something with file names.